# Validation Summary with JQuery in MVC 2

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I'm trying to get client validation working on my asp.net mvc 2 web application (Visual Studio 2010). The client side validation **IS** working. However the validation summary is not.

I'm including the following scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../content/scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../content/scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../content/scripts/MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js"></script>
```

Have this before this form is started

```
<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
```

and inside the form is

```
<%: Html.ValidationSummary("There are some errors to fix.", new { @class = "warning_box" })%>
<p>
    <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name) %><br />
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name) %>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name, "*") %>
</p>
```

I have that latest version of MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js from the MvcFutures download, but it doesn't look like it supports Validation Summary. I've tried correcting this by setting extra options such as errorContainer and errorLabelContainer, but it looks like there's some more underlying issues with it.

Is there an updated / better version of this file around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I've found so far is a patch by Since Ince that can be found at [jQuery.validate, and Html.ValidationSummary playing nice together](http://blogs.msdn.com/simonince/archive/2010/05/17/jquery-validate-and-html-validationsummary-playing-nice-together.aspx).